# How to use OIDC with custom internal Provider

Tags: quarkus

We have a standard OIDC/OAuth2 provider.
With Quarkus I am able to do setup and do auto discover with openid well know configurations. So overall it works fine.

- How to customize the URL. We need to add few parameters viz. Resource
- customize the callback url
- handle tokes differently

Can someone guide on this.
How to pass resource server public resgister URI in quarkus.

I see all examples only use keycloak , but we cant use as we already have predefined Federation service and Authorization service built in.

Do guide with some directions to make quarkus customize the urls.